# Using Object Mapping with Kinvey

Tags: swift, xcode, kinvey

I have an array of objects I'm trying to get out of one of my collections. I've followed along using their docs and also some Googling and I believe I'm close to the solution, however not close enough. Here's what I have:

```
class Clothing: Entity {

    var categories: [Category]!
    var gender: String!

    override class func collectionName() -> String {
    //return the name of the backend collection corresponding to this entity
        return "categories"
    }

    override func propertyMapping(_ map: Map) {
        super.propertyMapping(map)

        categories <- map["clothing"]
        gender <- map["gender"]

    }
}


class Category: NSObject, Mappable{

    var title: String?
    var image: String?

    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["category"]
        image <- map["image"]
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the right gender, but the array of categories doesn't seem to get mapped to the Category object. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

your model actually have one issue, as you can see at https://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/datastore#Model you should use `let categories = List<Category>()` instead of `var categories: [Category]!`. Here's the model that and test and worked:

```
import Kinvey

class Clothing: Entity {

    let categories = List<Category>()
    var gender: String!

    override class func collectionName() -> String {
        //return the name of the backend collection corresponding to this entity
        return "clothing"
    }

    override func propertyMapping(_ map: Map) {
        super.propertyMapping(map)

        categories <- ("categories", map["categories"])
        gender <- ("gender", map["gender"])

    }
}

class Category: Object, Mappable{

    var title: String?
    var image: String?

    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- ("category", map["category"])
        image <- ("image", map["image"])
    }
}
```

and here's a sample code how to save a new `Clothing` object

```
let casualCategory = Category()
casualCategory.title = "Casual"

let shirtCategory = Category()
shirtCategory.title = "Shirt"

let clothing = Clothing()
clothing.gender = "male"
clothing.categories.append(shirtCategory)
clothing.categories.append(casualCategory)

dataStore.save(clothing) { (result: Result<Clothing, Swift.Error>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let clothing):
        print(clothing)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually changed up a lot of my collections because of this but now I can revert back to what I originally mocked up.